# How to change a sub component data in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using a component with tabs inside. In the Head component(parent):

```
<v-btn @click="setSelectedTab('Set') "> ... 
<component :is="selectedTab"></component>
```

In the Set component(child component), I use some emits that will change the data.

```
 <div>
    <head-set
      v-show="showHeadSet"
      @settings="
        showHeadSet = false;
        showScreenSettings = true;
      "
      @robotix="
        showHeadSet = false;
        showRobotix = true;
      "
    >
    </head-set>
    <Robotix v-show="showRobotix"></Robotix>
    <screen-settings v-show="showScreenSettings"></screen-settings>
  </div>

<script>
data() {
    return {
      showHeadSet: true,
      showRobotix: false,
      showScreenSettings: false,
    };
  },
</script>
```

When the button is pressed (`@click="setSelectedTab('Set') "`), I want the data in the Set(child component) to return as in the beginning(`showHeadSet: true,showRobotix: false,showScreenSettings: false,`).

Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to pass data to your child components in your case would be to use properties.

Your parent component would looks something like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-btn @click="setSelectedTab('Set') "> ... </v-btn>
    <component :is="selectedTab" :settings="yourSettings"></component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    yourSettings: {
      showHeadSet: true,
      showRobotix: false,
      showScreenSettings: false
    }
  },

  methods: {
    setSelectedTab() {
      // your code
      this.yourSettings = {
        showHeadSet: true,
        showRobotix: false,
        showScreenSettings: false
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In your child components you'll have to add the props definition like this

```
<script>
export default  {
  props: {
    settings: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

You can use the props like computed or data variables and overwrite the settings as you need them to be. In the `setSelectedTab` method of the parent component you just overwrite the data back to the defaults.

You can check the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html) on more info about props.

Comment: it didn't work that way. I think I made an incomplete explanation. I have 4 tab buttons. This button takes us to the set component. In the set component, the main component is head-set. The buttons in the head-set direct us to robotix and screen-settings. As a result, the button in the main component needs to make the selected tab a Set component and change the data in it.